# How to assign saltstack pillar values from Jenkins comma separated input parameters?

Tags: jenkinsfile, salt, groovy

I have a Jenkins job with string parameter as target "server1,server2". Jenkins pipeline script is expected to execute the job on server1 and server2 respectively.
There is a common salt sls file that updates directory permissions and groups on both servers. The expectation is when the job is executed on server1, a group by name xx-server1-yy must be created and updated in server1, similarly a group xx-server2-yy be created in server2 only.
One sls file for Jenkins job on multiple servers with groups created specific to each server. What is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say how the sls file is executed.

- One way would be to [pass pillars on command line](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/getstarted/config/pillar.html#salt-pillar-on-the-command-line):

```
salt '*' state.apply ftpsync pillar='{"ftpusername": "test", "ftppassword": "0ydyfww3giq8"}'
```

- Or you can set the group name as a [grain](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/grains/) on the minion in advance.
- Yet another way would be to set the group name as a jinja variable in the sls formula, depending on the hostname grain. Assuming your host names are set and standardized.